# Error in starting application created in spring boot with JPA and mysql

Tags: java, mysql, spring, jpa

I was developing a simple spring boot application that fetches and inserts data to a database i created using MySql workbench. I keep getting the error below.

```
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2018-09-14 11:35:14.282 ERROR 11268 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: class demo.fabric.Employee not found while looking for property: id
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1699) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:573) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:495) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1089) ~[spring-context-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:859) ~[spring-context-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550) ~[spring-context-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:140) ~[spring-boot-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:780) [spring-boot-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:412) [spring-boot-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:333) [spring-boot-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1277) [spring-boot-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1265) [spring-boot-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at com.example.studentInfo.StudentOnlineInfoApplication.main(StudentOnlineInfoApplication.java:10) [classes/:na]
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: class demo.fabric.Employee not found while looking for property: id
    at org.hibernate.internal.util.ReflectHelper.reflectedPropertyClass(ReflectHelper.java:220) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.mapping.SimpleValue.setTypeUsingReflection(SimpleValue.java:482) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.source.internal.hbm.ModelBinder.bindSimpleEntityIdentifier(ModelBinder.java:726) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.source.internal.hbm.ModelBinder.bindEntityIdentifier(ModelBinder.java:350) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.source.internal.hbm.ModelBinder.bindRootEntity(ModelBinder.java:245) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.source.internal.hbm.ModelBinder.bindEntityHierarchy(ModelBinder.java:192) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.source.internal.hbm.HbmMetadataSourceProcessorImpl.processEntityHierarchies(HbmMetadataSourceProcessorImpl.java:144) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess$1.processEntityHierarchies(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:218) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:265) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:861) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:888) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:57) ~[spring-orm-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365) ~[spring-orm-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:390) ~[spring-orm-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:377) ~[spring-orm-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:341) ~[spring-orm-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1758) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1695) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    ... 16 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.spi.ClassLoadingException: Unable to load class [demo.fabric.Employee]
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.classForName(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:348) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.util.ReflectHelper.reflectedPropertyClass(ReflectHelper.java:216) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    ... 33 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Could not load requested class : demo.fabric.Employee
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl$AggregatedClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:336) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.classForName(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:345) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    ... 34 common frames omitted
```

Below is my POM.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.example.studentInfo</groupId>
<artifactId>studentOnlineInfo</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<name>studentOnlineInfo</name>
<description>A web project which implements simple write and read to the database</description>
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.5.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
</project>
```

Here is my application.properties file

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/studentInfo
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=Christensen001
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.mvc.view.prefix=/WEB-INF/jsps/
spring.mvc.view.suffix=.jsp
```

This is my Entity class

```
package com.example.studentInfo.entities;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;
@Entity
@Table(name="studenData")
public class StudentInformation {
@Id
private long id;
@Column(name="sreg_num")
private String reg_num;
@Column(name="semail")
private String email;
@Column(name="sname")
private String name;
@Column(name="sage")
private int age;
@Column(name="sstate")
private String state;
@Column(name="scity")
private String city;
public long getId() {
    return id;
}
public void setId(long id) {
    this.id = id;
}
public String getReg_num() {
    return reg_num;
}
public void setReg_num(String reg_num) {
    this.reg_num = reg_num;
}
public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}
public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}
public String getName() {
    return name;
}
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
public int getAge() {
    return age;
}
public void setAge(int age) {
    this.age = age;
}
public String getState() {
    return state;
}
public void setState(String state) {
    this.state = state;
}
public String getCity() {
    return city;
}
public void setCity(String city) {
    this.city = city;
}
public StudentInformation(long id, String reg_num, String email, String name, int age, String state, String city) {
    super();
    this.id = id;
    this.reg_num = reg_num;
    this.email = email;
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
    this.state = state;
    this.city = city;
}
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "StudentInformation [id=" + id + ", reg_num=" + reg_num + ", email=" + email + ", name=" + name
            + ", age=" + age + ", state=" + state + ", city=" + city + "]";
}
} </pre>
```

studentInfoApplication.java

```
package com.example.studentInfo;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class StudentOnlineInfoApplication {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(StudentOnlineInfoApplication.class, args);
}
}
```

How do i resolve this?

Comment: `Could not load requested class : demo.fabric.Employee`. Make the class visible in the classpath perhaps ...

Comment: Or figure out where you're referring to it and update the reference appropriately.

Comment: Please also include the code for `StudentOnlineInfoApplication`.

Comment: i just added it @samabcde

Comment: @BillyFrost, i didnt create any class like that.

Comment: Your code refers to it. Code initiated from `com.example.studentInfo.StudentOnlineInfoApplication.main` tries to instantiate it. So you go and search through all config etc and you find it and remove it

Comment: I suggest you to do a global search on 'demo.fabric.Employee' to see how this class is referenced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update**

Step 1:  Likely a corrupt download. Try removing ~/.m2/respository and run mvn clean install

2. If it does not work then will recommend to create new project from [SPRING INITIALIZR](https://start.spring.io/) with all required dependencies.
3. If this not even works then will recommend to reinstall your IDE as there might be some issues in installing/caching it.

Your Entity seems fine loading as I tried with same Spring Boot configuration. so seems issue is mapping between your mysql table and entity so check you have id as primary key defined in table.

or better to use below property in application.properties to auto create your tables first time.later you can update this property to `none`

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL57Dialect
```

Just a suggestion to manage id configuration like this for primary key.

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "id")
private Long id;
```

**Update**

1. Remove `@Autowired` from `StudentsController.java`
2. Remove `tomcat-embed-core` dependencies as spring boot annotation has already embedded it.

   ```
   <dependency>
     <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
     <artifactId>tomcat-embed-core</artifactId>
     <scope>provided</scope>
   </dependency>
   ```
3. run your code base now.

Comment: which doesnt answer the question (error loading class). There is no reason to always get ids generated

Comment: true I have updated my answer this just as a suggestion and actual reason might be table..

Comment: Can you please show me your table if you have already created??

Comment: i used: `create table studentData(
id int  PRIMARY KEY,
sreg_num varchar(11),
semail varchar(50),
sname varchar(50),
sage int,
sstate varchar(50),
scity varchar(50)
) ` to create my database from mysql workbench installed on my pc

Comment: what is this class Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Could not load requested class : demo.fabric.Employee??

Comment: I haven't created any such class in any of my projects, and don't seem to undestand where it is coming from

Comment: are you using any hibernate config etc??can you please show me any config xml or something you are using??

Comment: is it possible for you to share code on GitHub and let me know repo path

Comment: @kj007, ok let me push the code and send you a link ASAP

Comment: @EtekaChristopher check my updated answer where you need to remove items.

Comment: I could able to run your code successfully, please clean and rebuild project that might help as there is no issue in your code which you shared on GitHub after fixing issue I mentioned

Comment: I think its an installation problem, i observed that some folders does not exist in my .m2/org/springframework/...

Comment: Run mvn clean install command or clean project then rebuild should work

Comment: Alright @kj007, one last question, what version of spring are you using.

Comment: @kj007, i have implemented your latest update and still facing same problem, do you think i should change the version of STS installed on my PC??

Comment: Can you please create a fresh project from https://start.spring.io/ by adding your dependencies and please check, this is really weird as not working at your side. after clean project, etc

Comment: `Failure to transfer org.apache.maven:maven-archiver:pom:3.1.1 from https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven:maven-archiver:pom:3.1.1 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Remote host closed connection during handshake`

Comment: Maven has to be reinstall, please uninstalled first one and reinstall latest version

Comment: @EtekaChristopher that's great, I have updated my answer, could you please accept my answer if it helped you to solve the problem.